# How to plot line plot with vertical-based data (well-log)?

Tags: python, altair

I was trying to plot geophysics data (well-log) into a scatter plot in Altair using mark_line function, but the line plot is not connecting the dots/ points from top-bottom, but rather from left-right. If you see figure on the left, the data is distributed vertically as clearly seen, in the middle is the result using mark_line, and on the right is the one I wanted, just flipped the X and Y axis.

Is there any way to make a plot to behave just like left figure, but in line encoding?

Or perhaps some form of hacks to flipped the display on the right figure?

```
chart1 = alt.Chart(w).mark_point(color='green').encode(
  alt.X('GR', scale=alt.Scale(domain=[0,300])),
  alt.Y('DEPT', scale=alt.Scale(domain=[7000, 7100])),
).interactive()


chart2 = alt.Chart(w).mark_line(color='green').encode(
  alt.X('GR', scale=alt.Scale(domain=[0,300])),
  alt.Y('DEPT', scale=alt.Scale(domain=[7000, 7100])),
).interactive()



chart3 = alt.Chart(w).mark_line(color='green').encode(
  alt.Y('GR', scale=alt.Scale(domain=[0,300])),
  alt.X('DEPT', scale=alt.Scale(domain=[7000, 7100])),
).interactive()

chart1 | chart2 | chart3
```

[Plot using Altair](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U54PL.png)

*For those who needs more information, this is a typical dataset from borehole geophysics data/ well-log. Data (GR) is displayed in vertical line, against depth (DEPT).*

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please use the [Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/) for provide a [mcve]

Comment: There is a sample of drawing a line connected to a scatter plot in the [official reference](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/connected_scatterplot.html). I feel that if you swap the x-axis and y-axis of this and start from the top of the y-axis, you can draw the intended graph. However, this is only if the structure of the data is correct.

Comment: @r-beginners , thanks for bringing this up. I figured out why the previous code won't work. Mainly because the default scatters plot in mark_line will connect the data alongside X-axis. To specify a customed path (Y-axis/ DEPT), I add an additional attribute order='DEPT' to allow the line to follow the Y-axis. Problem solved!

Comment: @arie_wjy Could you post your solution as an answer to this question and mark it as solved by clicking the checkmark after posting the solution? This helps others with similar problems to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I tested so far, Altair scatters plot using `mark_line` will always follow the X-axis by default. Therefore, in the case where you want to plot data across Y-axis, one has to specify the ***order*** of the connecting line. In the following, I add `order = 'DEPT'` which was the Y-axis in the plot.

```
alt.Chart(
  w

).mark_line(
  color='green', 
  point=True,

).encode(
  alt.X('GR', scale=alt.Scale(domain=[0,250])),
  alt.Y('DEPT', sort = 'descending',scale=alt.Scale(domain=[7000, 7030])),
  order = 'DEPT' #this has to be added to make sure the plot is following the order of Y-axis, DEPT

).configure_mark(
  color = 'red'

).interactive()
```

Result:

[image: Scatter plot with vertical data using Altair]